# Property 'profile' does not exist on type 'void'

Tags: angular

I have an angular 5 app where I've converted some functions I originally developed in AngularJs.

I have one function, where I compare two arrays and splice out duplicates.

But for some reason, in Angular (2+) I get the following error:

```
[21:22:15]  typescript: src/pages/customize-share/customize-share.ts, line: 74 
            Property 'profile' does not exist on type 'void'. 

      L73:  this.contact.shared.emails.map(function(val) {
      L74:    this.profile.emails.indexOf(val.email_address) < 0 ? this.emailArray.splice(val,1) : '';
      L75:  });
```

Am I missing initializing an array type here?

FYI, emails has the following interface as its type:

```
export interface IEmail {
    email_type: string;
    email_address: string;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Probably due to the scope of `this`.

Try:

```
this.contact.shared.emails.map((val) => {
    this.profile.emails.indexOf(val.email_address) < 0 ? this.emailArray.splice(val,1) : '';
});
```

Comment: Thanks, Zze. I made the change but now I get a red line below (val.email_address): [ts] Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type 'IEmail'.
(property) IEmail.email_address: string.

Comment: I added the interface to the original post.

Answer (score 1):

Most probably the error is because of the scope of `this`, In order to avoid this use `=>` arrow function instead of writing `anonymous function`

```
this.contact.shared.emails.map((val) => {
  this.profile.emails.indexOf(val.email_address) < 0 ? this.emailArray.splice(val,1) : '';
});
```

For more information about arrow function you can refer this article

- https://angular-2-training-book.rangle.io/handout/features/arrow_functions.html

Comment: Thanks Pardeep, I made the change but now I get a red line below (val.email_address): [ts] Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type 'IEmail'. (property) IEmail.email_address: string. I added the interface to the original post. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the function(val) and using val => like so:

```
this.contact.shared.emails.map(val => {
    this.profile.emails.indexOf(val.email_address) < 0 ? this.emailArray.splice(val,1) : ''; 
});
```

Comment: Already there are 2 answeres having same content , what's new in your ?

Comment: Yea i noticed. Your answers didn't show up when I was in the process of writing mine. Guess the only thing is you don't necessarily need the () around the val this is being sent from the .map() function.

Comment: This is true, but it does provide a simple little trick that the person may not of known about that is useful.